# How to decode a column in URL format?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, decode, urldecode

Do you know how to decode the 'campaign' column below in PySpark? The records in this column are strings in URL format:

```
+--------------------+------------------------+
|user_id             |campaign                |
+--------------------+------------------------+
|alskd9239as23093    |MM+%7C+Cons%C3%B3rcios+%|
|lfifsf093039388     |Aquisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o+%7C |
|kasd877191kdsd999   |Aquisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o+%7C |
+--------------------+------------------------+
```

I know that it is possible to do this with the `urllib` library in Python. However, my dataset is large and it takes too long to convert it to a pandas dataframe. How to do this with a Spark DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert to intermediate pandas dataframe, you can use pyspark user defined functions (udf) to `unquote` the quoted string:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from urllib.parse import unquote

df.withColumn('campaign', F.udf(unquote, F.StringType())('campaign'))
```

If there are `null` values in the `campaign` column, then you have to do null check before unquoting the strings:

```
f = lambda s: unquote(s) if s else s
df.withColumn('campaign',  F.udf(f, F.StringType())('campaign'))
```

---

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
|          user_id|         campaign|
+-----------------+-----------------+
| alskd9239as23093|MM+|+Consórcios+%|
|  lfifsf093039388|      Aquisição+||
|kasd877191kdsd999|      Aquisição+||
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, a received the following error message: "An error occurred while calling o180.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times". What is "F"? Is it from "from pyspark.sql import functions as F"? Thanks

Comment: The error was caused by: "Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback" and by "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Comment: Yes, `F` is the alias for `pyspark.sql.functions`

Answer (score 2):

These are supposed to work:

**Spark 3.5+**

```py
F.url_decode('campaign')
```

**Spark 3.4+**

```py
F.expr("url_decode(campaign)")
```

However, it seems your value "MM+%7C+Cons%C3%B3rcios+%" is not formatted properly:

> [CANNOT_DECODE_URL] The provided URL cannot be decoded: MM+%7C+Cons%C3%B3rcios+%. Please ensure that the URL is properly formatted and try again.

It works, when I try it without this input row:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('lfifsf093039388', 'Aquisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o+%7C'),
     ('kasd877191kdsd999', 'Aquisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o+%7C')],
    ['user_id', 'campaign'])

df.withColumn('campaign', F.url_decode('campaign')).show()
# +-----------------+-----------+
# |          user_id|   campaign|
# +-----------------+-----------+
# |  lfifsf093039388|Aquisição ||
# |kasd877191kdsd999|Aquisição ||
# +-----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What's a good way to handle this error? Sometimes you have invalid values ("foo%20%bar" is another example), where python's urllib unquote() can handle but pyspark's function url_decode() fails with the "[CANNOT_DECODE_URL]" error.